# How to use ServiceStack MVC library without the default.htm page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I am using Servicestack.MVC.Host nuget package in an application.this package sets the deafult view to the included default.htm file. i have tried over riding this to render to a view of my choosing (as default) using the routes.map method in global.asax but this doesn't work at all.is there another configuration setting somewhere wher i could make this change.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppHost Configure()

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {DefaultRedirectPath = "/Foo" });
```